# Infinite Loop with Vue Router Global Before Guards

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, vue-router

I'm trying to redirect the user with Firebase Auth and Vue Router.

The point is that when Router redirects the user to '/' nothing is displayed in the website (completely white screen).

I know that I'm doing something wrong, but I don't know exactly what is wrong.

This is how looks like my 'router.js' file:

```js
const router = new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '*',
      redirect: '/login'
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      redirect: '/login'
    },
    {
      path: '/login',
      name: 'Login',
      component: Login
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'Home',
      component: Home,
      meta: {
        authenticated: true
      }
    }
  ]
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
  let approbation = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.authenticated)
  if (approbation && !user) {
    next('/login')
  } else if (!approbation && user && from.path !== '/') {
    next('/')
  }
})

export default router
```

Comment: The `routes` option is ordered. If you put `path: '*'` at first it will alway matched (even you redirect to `/login`, `/login` will match it anyway).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that neither `if (approbation && !user)` nor `else if (!approbation && user && from.path !== '/')` is true. Since you're not calling `next()` after you `if-else` block, the hook is never resolved and vue-router doesn't know where to go.

Make sure to add a call to `next()` after you `if-else` blocks.